# Amazon Product Advertising API - Item Not Accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-product-advertising-api

When I'm trying to do a lookup against B001F7AHOG, an Apple Ipod, I'm getting the error:

> This item is not accessible through the Product Advertising API.

Why is this, and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4):

Some products are just missing from their PA database.

If it doesn't show up here: https://asintool.com/asin-lookup.php?text=B001F7AHOG&ip=1 you can bet its just not in the database.

I had read somewhere this week that there was a reason for apple products specifically having this problem, but I can't find it now.

PS: Make sure you are using the correct country code. ('de', 'com', 'co.uk', 'ca', 'fr', 'co.jp', 'it', 'cn', 'es')

Answer (score 3):

Apple ipods are missing from their PA database. I met the same issue today.

Here is what I found: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=98171#

Not very useful though, frustrating.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ErrorMessages.html

> AWS.ECommerceService.ItemNotAccessible
>
> Some products cannot be manipulated or viewed using Product
>   Advertising API. You will receive this error message when the product
>   ID you use in your request is not available through Product
>   Advertising API.